# DOMPDF IN SYMFONY : cache:clear

Tags: symfony, caching, reset, dompdf

I have a problem to edit my pdf with DOMPDF in Symfony 5.2.

When I run the generation of my PDF, the first time everything works, but when I start over I get a failure.

I generate a trombinoscope (image + text). I guess it's from the cache somewhere but I don't know how to do it.

TrombiController

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

    public function TrombiPlayers(Request $request, PlayerRepository $playerRepository)
    {

        $ids = $_POST['ids'];
        $numbers = $_POST['numbers'];

        $team = $_POST['team'];
        $team = strtoupper($team);

        $nums    = array_intersect_key($numbers, array_flip($ids));

        $players = [];

        foreach ($nums as $key => $number) {
            $player = $playerRepository->trombiPlayer($key, $number);
            array_push($players, $player);
        }

        $pdfOptions = new Options();
        $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
        $pdfOptions->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

        $dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);

        $html = $this->renderView('pdf/trombiPDF.html.twig', [
            'team' => $team,
            'players' => $players
        ]);

        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

        $dompdf->render();

        $dompdf->stream($team . "mypdf.pdf", [
            "Attachment" => true
        ]);

        unset($dompdf);
        unset($html);

        return new Response("The PDF file has been succesfully generated !");
    }
```

trombiPDF.html.twig

```
<html>
        <h2> EQUIPE : {{ team }} </h2>

         <table class="table" id="trombiPlayerTable">

            <tr class="row1">
                {% for i in range(0, 3) %}
                    {% if (players[i] is defined) %}
                        <td>
                            <div class="card" style="max-width: 15rem;">
                                {% if ((players[i].photo_file_name) is not null ) %}
                                    <img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('/uploads/photos/'~ players[i].photo_file_name)) }}" class="card-img-top"/>                                    
                                {% else %}
                                    <img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('/uploads/photos/NoPicture.jpg')) }}" class="card-img-top"/>
                                {% endif %}

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div> {{players[i].number}} </div>
                                    <div class="textBold">{{players[i].name|capitalize }} </div>
                                    <div>{{players[i].birth|date("m/d/Y")}} </div>                                                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
...
```

How to reset after generating the pdf ?